# whenever account rating is warm then update account description field with warm and create related opportunity

Tags: trigger

**My error is -  Whenever I'm updating Rating='warm' then description field is updating with warm- but issue is I'm unable to create opportunity.**

```
trigger Acct on Account (before insert,before update)
{
    List<Opportunity> op=new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Account ac:Trigger.New){
        if(ac.Rating=='Warm'){
            ac.Description=ac.Rating;

        Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
        opp.Name=ac.Name;
        opp.StageName='Prospecting';
        opp.CloseDate=System.today();
        opp.Id=opp.AccountId;
            op.add(opp);
        }
    }
    insert op;
}
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting an error on this line:

```
opp.Id=opp.AccountId;
```

First, you may not specify `Id` of a record that you want to insert,
Second, what are you trying to achieve there? Seeing that you do not set `AccountId` anywhere, this line is interpreted as:

```
opp.Id = null;
```

Comment: really looks like it should be opp.accountId =ac.id;

Comment: @DaveHumm it does, but it will still fail in a `before insert` case

Comment: yes, got to admit I don't see why this can't be after insert on account.

Comment: @DaveHumm probably because it is not allowed to make any changes to `Trigger.new` in an after trigger(talking about this line: `ac.Description=ac.Rating;`), so OP will have to query the records first.